# Как иерархическим запросом с соединением таблиц (JOIN) конкатенировать значение колонки?

Tags: sql, oracle

Имею две таблицы ([создание таблиц и данные](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f6f4058471a42f6ccbede6237a92bd97)):

```
DAT      A        B        ID       NUM      PART    
-------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
1234     aa       bb       None     0        0       
1235     ab       ba       8b       2        2       
1238     ab       ba       8b       1        2       

DAT      TST     
-------- --------
1234     ss tr rt
1235     ab rt   
1238     er ty ui
```

На выходе пытаюсь получить следующую таблицу:

```
 a   b   res
 --  --  ---------------
 aa  bb  ss tr rt
 ab  ba  er ty ui ab rt
```

Пытаюсь объединить таблицы по колонке `dat`, затем пытаюсь склеить ячейки для колонки `tst`, где:

- `part` - количество частей
- `num` - номер части
- `id` - id склейки.

Примерно следующим образом пытаюсь склеивать и выполнить конкатенацию:

```
select a, b,
    REPLACE(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(tst, '*&^%'),'*&^%') AS res
from(
    select dat, a, b, id, num, part from one
) C
left join two t1 on t1.dat = c.dat
WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
START WITH NUM = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR a = a
AND PRIOR B = B
AND PRIOR ID = ID
AND PRIOR PART = part - 1
```

Просьба, подсказать оптимальный и более быстрый по исполнению вариант. Возможно ли выполнить подобный запрос без `UNION` с добавлением строк где `id` является `None`.

Comment: Не совсем все понятно. Поясните, как вы "построили" ожидаемый результат? Почему в таблице two  нет колонки num?

Comment: @0xdb, структура таблицы two изначально не содержит колонку num, общей колонкой по которой связываю является dat, из данной таблицы забираю колонку tst и склеиваю значения где из первой таблицы id является id по которому группируется и производится конкатенация, последовательность склеивания завязана на колонки num, в результате я получаю склеивание сток где id не содержит None из за этого приходится через Union добавлять подобные строки, 
Возможно ли подобную конкатенатинаю выполнить другим способом более производительным и избавиться от нагромождения union?

Comment: Хорошо,  по порядку. Начнём с [соединения таблиц](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=90bf53e153a713913ccd30479464333c), как после него получить  ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не стоит использовать иерархические запросы там, где иерархии нету.

Такой [простой запрос](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=39e4132f02ac9442d4d2a532a44d96db) на данных из вопроса вернёт ожидаемый результат:

```
select 
    a, b, id, listagg (tst, ' ') within group (order by num asc) res
from one t1
join two t2 on t2.dat = t1.dat
group by a, b, id

A        B        ID       RES             
-------- -------- -------- ----------------
aa       bb       None     ss tr rt        
ab       ba       8b       er ty ui ab rt
```

Comment: К сожалению, пока не добрался до пк, как доберусь попробую, хотел утончить, если с листаг буду упираться в ограничение склеивания дополнительная конвертация в клоб сильно подвесит запрос?

Comment: @xcplat _если с листаг буду упираться в ограничение склеивания_, тогда надо будет другое решение, sys_connect_by_path тоже не поможет. Давайте разберёмся сначало с этим вопросом, а потом будем думать дальше.

Comment: к сожалению, по вашему способу возвращается ошибка ORA-30482: DISTINCT option not allowed for this function, что на dbfiddle что на своей машине

Comment: @xcplat К сожалению, у вас устаревшая версия (какая?), не беда, испраавим. Посмотрите тестовые данные, с ними всё в порядке? Под вопросом уже есть комментарий, на который вы не ответили.

Comment: если вы про версию Oracle, то  12.1.0.2.0, 
с тестовыми данными все в порядке, все таже структура, первая таблица с идентификаторами вторая с данными которые конкатенирую на основе первой таблицы, относительно вопроса:
как после него получить ожидаемый результат?
к сожалению, возникают трудности с переносом запроса сюда, он не выполняется как на рабочей машине, но смысл в том, что путем иерархического запроса провожу конкатенацию

Comment: _вторая с данными, которые конкатенирую на основе первой таблицы_, таблицы связаны только через dat, т.е. как  конкатенировать tst? Почему в ожидаемом рез. `er ty ui ab rt`, а не `ab rt er ty ui`? В ответе отсортировал по алфавиту, но это скорее всего не то, что требуется.

Comment: допустил ошибку всеже в переносе данных, [https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=43812f4912df2b63437f058b6a2d9150]
поправил данные, _Почему в ожидаемом рез. er ty ui ab rt, а не ab rt er ty ui_ 
порядок склейки num, соответсвенно id = 8b имеет 2 части о чем говорится в purt и порядок склеивания num, num = 1 (er ty ui) num =2 (ab rt), в результате получаю `er ty ui ab rt`

Comment: Ааа, теперь понятней. Что ожидается в DAT, 1235  или 1238?

Comment: в DAT, являются некоторыми идентификаторами которые позволяют корректно сджойнить обе таблицы, ожидаем оба 1235 и 1238, сейчас оба значения корректны в обоих таблицах джойнится корректно без дублирования строк

Comment: _ожидаем оба 1235 и 1238_, оба не можем, строка всего одна. Поправте в вопросе ожидаемый результат, или  DAT надо убрать, или один из двух.

Comment: DAT в конечном убираем, он на нужен только для объединение таблиц, сейчас поправлю

Comment: опробовал данный способ, примерно на 15% быстрее исполняется, остается вопрос, как быть если результат склеивания будет превышать допустимый, ранее я приводил к clob чтобы избавится от ошибки, в данном варианте возможно выполнить подобное?

Comment: Так понял, этот вопрос решен. _возможно выполнить подобное?_, да, возможно, но это по сути новый вопрос. Задайте его с примером данных. Проверте в реальных данных, действительно ли такое возможно. listagg пока не расширили для clob, потому что это мало кому нужно.

Comment: хорошо, благодарю, потестирую если начну упираться в ограничение задам вопрос

Comment: Рад был помочь!

Comment: можете подсказать, можно ли в данной конструкции вывести колонку где будет указанно из скольки частей состоит склейка? приблизительно понимаю логику но с исполнением что-то не выходит

Comment: `count (tst), listagg (....)`

Comment: благодарю, все на много проще оказалось) я от сложного пошел)

Comment: столкнулся с тем, что когда в таблице много id равное None склеивает и превращает в кашу результат, можно как то исключить что бы если встречается None не производил склеивание оставлял в Result значение tst, так понимаю тут через case придется перебирать?

Comment: Сделайте пример на фиддле (ссылка есть в вопросе). Или лучше задайте сразу новый  вопрос с таким примером.